# bootstrap modal inside a modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

How can I build a bootstrap modal inside another modal using Jquery .The first modal should be there in the background. When I refereed bootstrap documentation seen that Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code. Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might wanna try the Bootstrap Modal plugin ([Demo here - Stackable](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/), [Source here](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal))

```
<div id="stack1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Stack One</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-tabindex="1">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-tabindex="2">
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" href="#stack2">Launch modal</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="stack2" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Stack Two</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-tabindex="1">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-tabindex="2">
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" href="#stack3">Launch modal</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="stack3" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Stack Three</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-tabindex="1">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-tabindex="2">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to add both .js file from the src folder.