# Bootstrap modal inside modal background scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal with a long content and a button that opens another modal. When I close the inner modal, the outer modal is stuck. It cannot be scrolled, rather the background begins to scroll.

I have found a few questions relating to modal and scrolling like [bootstrap modal inside a modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380323/bootstrap-modal-inside-a-modal) and [Prevent BODY from scrolling when a modal is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538868/prevent-body-from-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-opened), but my issue doesn't seem to be replicated here.

I have forked a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vcko6s2/2/) from [Bootstrap 3: prevent modal inside modal to trigger (hidden.bs.modal) every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662779/bootstrap-3-prevent-modal-inside-modal-to-trigger-hidden-bs-modal-every-time) to demonstate this issue. After clicking on the Cancel from the second modal, the first modal is stuck.

code:

```js
$('#btnUploadCancel').click(function() {
  $('#uploadImage').modal('toggle');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open demo modal</button>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum .... long content
</p>
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Demo Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadImage" class="btn btn-primary">Upload image</a>
        </p>
        Lorem ipsum ... long content
        <p>

        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal" id="uploadImage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="uploadImage-title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="uploadImage-title">Upload new image</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Testing Area
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnUploadCancel">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Accept</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your javascript to leave first modal open like this -

```
    $('#btnUploadCancel').click(function () {
    $('#uploadImage').modal('toggle');

    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot @t-shah

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var idx = $('.modal:visible').length;
        $(this).css('z-index', 1040 + (10 * idx));
    });
    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var idx = ($('.modal:visible').length) - 1; // raise backdrop after animation.
        $('.modal-backdrop').not('.stacked').css('z-index', 1039 + (10 * idx));
        $('.modal-backdrop').not('.stacked').addClass('stacked'); 
    });
   $('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) { 
        var modal_length =  $('.modal:visible').length;
        if (modal_length>1)
        {
            $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
            $('.modal:visible').css("overflow-y","auto");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap modal when shown adds a new `modal-open` class to your `body` element. And when being closed, it removes the `modal-open` class.

So you only need to re-apply that class to your `body` element when closing the child modal. Here's the thing:

Add a new custom css class for the modals inside your parent modal.

in my case, I use `.child-modal`,

```
/* when using a modal within a modal, add this class on the child modal */
$(document).find('.child-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    console.log('hiding child modal');
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
});
```

html

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
     ...
     <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#other_modal" title="Help">
       Open the other modal
     </a>
     ...
</div>
<div class="modal fade child-modal" id="other_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   ... other codes here ...
</div>
```

See working snippet below:

```js
$('#btnUploadCancel').click(function() {
  $('#uploadImage').modal('toggle');
});


$(document).find('.child-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    console.log('hiding child modal');
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open demo modal</button>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum .... long content
</p>
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Demo Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadImage" class="btn btn-primary">Upload image</a>
        </p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        <p>

        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal child-modal" id="uploadImage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="uploadImage-title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="uploadImage-title">Upload new image</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Testing Area
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
          orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnUploadCancel">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Accept</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome. this is very useful.