# Bootstrap modal toggle between two scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have the following piece of javascript that switches between two bootstrap modals.

However, when the second modal appears, the Bootstrap class "modal-open" that gets attached to the body class when a modal is opened is not being added onto the second modal. And so the modal background then scrolls instead of the modal itself.

The fix I need to do is to add the class of "modal-open" to the body tag when the second #priorityModal is opened.

Can someone tell me how to add it to the below code?

```
function showDialog2() {
  $("#developmentModal").modal("hide");
  $("#priorityModal").modal("show");
}

$("#toggledevelopmentModal").on("click", function () {
  showDialog2();
});
```

Comment: It should be added automatically when you call `.modal("show")`. Where are your modals located in DOM?

Comment: They are the last items before the <scripts> tags and </body>

Comment: Try adding them inside body. I came accross this example http://codepen.io/alvaram/pen/luotA . Have a look

Answer (score 1):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40846279/bootstrap-modal-within-bootstrap-modal-breaks-inner-boostrap-modal-scrolling) may have the answer.

The removal of modal-open seems to be done in an event that fires after the "show" is done.
So putting it back on may need to be done in a handler on the hidden.bs.modal event. (That's how I got it working best in my own website.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to open a new popup only after previous one is closed.

```
var developmentModal = $("#developmentModal"),
    priorityModal = $("#priorityModal");

function showDialog2() {    
    developmentModal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        priorityModal.modal("show")
    });
    developmentModal.modal("hide");
}
```

That should be fine

Comment: Nothing happens at all unfortunately when i tried this. The first modal doesn't close, and the second doesn't open

Comment: This was the right idea, I just made it more robust in my example below (possibly now above).

Answer (score -1):

As documented...
[Bootstrap 4 Modal Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)

And here's what I did...

```
<div id="firstModal" class="modal fade">
    <a
        id="firstModalToSecondModalLink"
        data-target="secondModal"
        class="switch-modal-link"
        href="#"
    >Switch to Modal 2</a>
    <a
        id="firstModalToThirdModalLink"
        data-target="thirdModal"
        class="switch-modal-link"
        href="#"
    >Switch to Modal 3</a>
</div>

<script>
    var next_modal = false;
    $('.switch-modal-link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        next_modal = $('#'+$(this).attr('data-target'));
        $(this)
            .closest('.modal')
            .modal('hide')
            .on(
                'hidden.bs.modal',
                function() {
                    if(next_modal) {
                        next_modal.modal({
                            show: true
                        });
                        next_modal = false;
                    }
                }
            );
    });
</script>
```